# Getting mysql gem working with ruby-1.9.3 on rvm

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to setup mysql gem on ruby-1.9.3 installed with rvm. I want to set up the 'redmine'.  To install mysql gem I used -->

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config
```

When I issue --> RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate, I get

```
/Users/myth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:211: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- mysql
```

However I have successfully deployed redmine1.3 on default ruby1.8.7 installation of OSX with installing mysql gem the very same way.

I want to work on the latest trunk with ruby-1.9.3
How can I resolve the issue? I have been searching the mailing list and found similar posts, however could not solve the problem.

Comment: Does your database.yml try to use the mysql driver instead of the mysql2 driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also struggled with this question. I could not get redmine working with mysql and ruby 1.9.3.

The answer is very easy and simple. For ruby 1.9.3 together with redmine you have to use the gem `mysql2` !

In http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade#Option-1-Downloaded-release-targz-or-zip-file it is also written to change the database adapter from `mysql` to `mysql2`.

So install `gem install mysql2` and also keep sure to have a

`database.yml` with `msql2` adapter:

```
production:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: redmine
    host: localhost
    username: redmine
    password: redmine
    encoding: utf8
```